# JavaScript filtering by comparing two arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery

The DOM:

```
<div class='myDiv' data-catid='1,2,3'></div>
<div class='myDiv' data-catid='4,5'></div>
<div class='myDiv' data-catid='1,5,7'></div>
<div class='myDiv' data-catid='8,9'></div>
<div class='myDiv' data-catid='2,3,4'></div>
```

The JS:

```
var filters = [2, 4];
```

I want to loop through the `divs`, and hide the ones that doesn't have both of the category ID's in their `data-catid`.

I have this so far:

```
$('.myDiv').each(function(i, el){               

  var itemCategories = $(el).data('catId').split(',');

  // Do check and then hide with $(el).css('visibility', 'hidden') 
  // if doesn't contain both filter id's in 'itemCategories';

});
```

Comment: It'd be cool to see how you've tried filtering so far...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use **[`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)** method along with javascript **[`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)** method(or **[`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)** method can be used).

```js
var filters = [2, 4];

// get all elements with class `myDiv`
$('.myDiv')
  // filter out elements
  .filter(function() {
    // generate array from catid attribute
    var arr = $(this)
      // get data attribute value
      .data('catid')
      // split based on `,`
      .split(',')
      // parse the string array, it's optional 
      // if you are not parsing then convert Number to 
      // String while using with indexOf
      .map(Number);
    // check all catid presents 
    return !filters.every(function(v) {
      // check index of elements
      return arr.indexOf(v) > -1;
    });
    // or with `some` method 
    // return filters.some(function(v) { return arr.indexOf(v) === -1; });  
    // hide the elements
  }).hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='myDiv' data-catid='1,2,3'>1</div>
<div class='myDiv' data-catid='4,5'>2</div>
<div class='myDiv' data-catid='1,5,7'>3</div>
<div class='myDiv' data-catid='8,9'>4</div>
<div class='myDiv' data-catid='2,3,4'>5</div>
```

---

**FYI :** For older browser check [polyfill option of `every` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every#Polyfill).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I'm getting this error when I run it: "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).data(...).split is not a function"

Comment: @DeanGibson :  although change `$('.myDiv')` to `$('.myDiv[data-catid]')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) instead `.each()` to filtering selected element and use [`String.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) to check value exist in array.

```js
var filters = [2, 4];
$('.myDiv').filter(function(){               
    var num = $(this).data('catid').split(',').map(Number);  
    return num.indexOf(filters[0]) == -1 || num.indexOf(filters[1]) == -1
}).hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='myDiv' data-catid='1,2,3'>1</div>
<div class='myDiv' data-catid='4,5'>2</div>
<div class='myDiv' data-catid='1,5,7'>3</div>
<div class='myDiv' data-catid='8,9'>4</div>
<div class='myDiv' data-catid='2,3,4'>5</div>
```