# Filtering Arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Say I have the following two arrays:

```
var arrOne = [1, 4, 7];
var arrTwo = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var arrThree = [];
```

I'd like to itterate over `arrTwo` and if it contains an element that is also in `arrOne`, remove it from `arrTwo`, and insert it in `arrThree`. So looking at the above arrays the state of the arrays afterwards should look like this:

```
var arrOne = [1, 4, 7];
var arrTwo = [2, 3, 5];
var arrThree = [1, 4];
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction and the best way to go about this? If code is provided, a step-by-step explanation would really be appreciated so that I can understand what's going on.

Comment: even simple `for` loop can be used, What is your effort? You can get an idea from your previous question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39972283/javascript-filtering-by-comparing-two-arrays

Answer (score 5):

A simple for loop, matching with indexOf and splicing matches.

```js
var arrOne = [1, 4, 7];
var arrTwo = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var arrThree = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arrTwo.length; i++) {
  if (arrOne.indexOf(arrTwo[i]) >= 0) {
    arrThree.push(arrTwo[i]);
    arrTwo.splice(i, 1);
    i--;
  }
}

console.log(arrOne, arrTwo, arrThree)
```

[Array.IndexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

[Array.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Answer (score 3):

Look into the [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) library.  All the elements in arrOne that are also in arrTwo is called `_.intersection()`.

Answer (score 2):

Use simple while loop with [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) and [`Array#unshift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) methods.

```js
var arrOne = [1, 4, 7];
var arrTwo = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var arrThree = [];
// get length of array
var l = arrTwo.length;
// iterate over array from the end
while (l--) {
  // check value present in arrOne
  if (arrOne.indexOf(arrTwo[l]) > -1)
  // if present then remove and insert it
  // at the beginning of arrThree
    arrThree.unshift(arrTwo.splice(l, 1)[0])
}

console.log(arrTwo, arrThree);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can use filter function to filter array.
try with below code.

```
    var arrOne = [1, 4, 7];
    var arrTwo = [2, 3, 5, 1];
    var arrThree = [];

    function checkValue(a) {
        return !arrOne.indexOf(a);
    }

    function checkValue2(a) {
        return arrThree.indexOf(a);
    }
    function myFunction() {
        arrThree = arrTwo.filter(checkValue);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = arrThree ;
        arrTwo = arrTwo.filter(checkValue2);
        document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = arrTwo;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arrOne = [1, 4, 7];
var arrTwo = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];


var arrThree = diff(arrOne,arrTwo);//passes the two arrays
console.log(arrThree);


function diff(one, two){
  one.forEach(function(e1){ //iterate through the first array
  
    two.forEach(function(e2){//iterate through second
     
      if(e1 == e2) //checking if elements are equal
       two.pop(e2);//removing from second array
   
    });
 });
  return two; //returning new array
}
```

You can use underscore js for easy array operations, the difference operation  will be `_.difference([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [5, 2, 10]);`.

Answer (score 0):

```
   var array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
   var array2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

  var common = $.grep(array1, function(element) {
   return $.inArray(element, array2) !== -1;
  });

  console.log(common); // returns [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];        

  array2 = array2.filter(function(obj) {
   return array1.indexOf(obj) == -1;
  });

  // returns [7,8,9];
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the arrays are sorted you could read them in parallel : O(n) instead of O(n2). Don't use a library for such a simple problem, this is overkill :-)

```js
var i = 0, j = 0;
var a = [1, 4, 7];
var b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var c = [];

while (i < a.length && j < b.length) {
  if (a[i] < b[j]) i++;
  else if (a[i] > b[j]) j++;
  else c.push(b.splice(j, 1)[0]);
}

console.log("a " + toString(a));
console.log("b " + toString(b));
console.log("c " + toString(c));

function toString (v) {
  return "[ " + v.join(" ") + " ]";
}
```

Trace :

```
#0 init

  a = [ 1 4 7 ]
        i
  b = [ 1 2 3 4 5 ]
        j
  c = []

#1 a[i] = b[j] => move b[j] to c

  a = [ 1 4 7 ]
        i
  b = [ 2 3 4 5 ]
        j
  c = [ 1 ]

#2 a[i] < b[j] => increment i

  a = [ 1 4 7 ]
          i
  b = [ 2 3 4 5 ]
        j
  c = [ 1 ]

#3 a[i] > b[j] => increment j

  a = [ 1 4 7 ]
          i
  b = [ 2 3 4 5 ]
          j
  c = [ 1 ]

#4 a[i] > b[j] => increment j

  a = [ 1 4 7 ]
          i
  b = [ 2 3 4 5 ]
            j
  c = [ 1 ]

#5 a[i] = b[j] => move b[j] to c

  a = [ 1 4 7 ]
          i
  b = [ 2 3 5 ]
            j
  c = [ 1 4 ]

#6 a[i] < b[j] => increment i

  a = [ 1 4 7 ]
            i
  b = [ 2 3 5 ]
            j
  c = [ 1 4 ]

#7 a[i] > b[j] => increment j

  a = [ 1 4 7 ]
            i
  b = [ 2 3 5 ]
              j
  c = [ 1 4 ]

#8 j = length of b => done
```